# A jquery Object attribute in a javascript Class instance isn't working? but in debugging,the value is the right one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Creating _a.target is a little different.

It like this =>

```
var _a,_b

var A =function(jquery){

this.target = jquery

}

var B =function(jquery){

this.target =jquery;

_a = new A (this.target)

}

_b = new B($('#id'));
```

In debugging, _a.target shows right,it is the right $('#id'), but any Jquery method of_a.target is not working!!!!

```
_a.target.css('color','red') isn't working.

_a.target.offset() return {top:0,left:0}.
```

but

```
_a.target.css('color','red') works fine. 

_b.target.offset() return the right value {top:122,left:522.5}.
```

i just don't know how to deal with it?

anyone can help me out? thank a lot!

Comment: *"then the `_a.target.css('color','red')` doesn't work!!!!"* Yes, it does; [example](https://jsfiddle.net/31fpmk1u/). Put an [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button), the code you've having trouble with is slightly different from your code above.

Comment: **Now, if people could avoid posting speculative answers to the question, instead waiting until there's a real question here, that would be lovely.**

Comment: Re the edit: [Still works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/31fpmk1u/1/), both log the same offsets. Again: Put a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets in the question demonstrating the behavior.

Comment: It's possible you're running into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection), but that's a wild guess.

Comment: The real problem i deal with is more complicated. i think i just asked it in a wrong way,hahahah ~

Comment: Thanks  T.J. Crowder , i think you just bet on the right issue!!! hahaha~here's your chips! hahahah ~