# The function getElementsByTagName is not returning the proper order of a ul that has draggable list items

Tags: javascript, html

I have a unordered list and the li elements can be dragged and the order can be changed.  This works fine the problem happens I use this line of code:
var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
It will return HtmlCollection but in the original order and not the current order that the user has moved the list items into.

I captured a screenshot with Chrome on the order that the list is in after I have moved several of the li's around.  Notice how it is still ordered like it was shown initially?

[image]

But if I expand the [0 ... 99] tag I see the proper order.  (See how the top few have been moved?  This is the order I need to iterate through.)

[image]

And here is the html text.

```html
<ul id="first_" class="sortable_unstyled" data-sortable-id="0" aria-dropeffect="move">
  
  <li draggable="true" role="option" aria-grabbed="false" style="list-style-type: none;" id="first_li_0" >
    <div>
        <input id="first_sectionnumber_0" type="number" />
    </div>
  </li>
    <li draggable="true" role="option" aria-grabbed="false" style="list-style-type: none;" id="first_li_1" >
    <div>
        <input id="first_sectionnumber_1" type="number" />
    </div>
  </li>
  // There is more than a 100 more lis after these

  </ul>
```

The javascript function is:

```js
        function RenumberQuestionIndexes(ulObj) {
            var count = 0;
            var ul = document.getElementById(ulObj);
            var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
            var indexinput = ulObj + "order_index_";

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
            {
                if(items[i].style.display.indexOf('none') >= 0)
                {
                    document.getElementById(indexinput + i.toString()).value = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById(indexinput + i.toString()).value = count;

                    count++;
                }
            }
 
        }
```

So how can I iterate through that HtmlCollection items list and get the actual order that is currently displayed on the screen?

Comment: When are you calling `RenumberQuestionIndexes` ?`show the code where you are calling RenumberQuestionIndexes

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` will definitely give you a collection in the order of the elements in the DOM. how does your dragging script change their order? If the order you get from `getElementsByTagName` really isn't the order you're seeing, it sounds like it just does it visually (which would be odd).

Comment: Separately, beware of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection

Answer (score 0):

Well after alot of head banging.  I found that if I turned my var items into a array it will work.

So I changed the code to this:

```js
        function RenumberQuestionIndexes(ulObj) {
            var count = 0;
            var ul = document.getElementById(ulObj);
            var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
            var indexinput = ulObj + "order_index_";

            var a = Array.from(items);


            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
            {
                if(a[i].style.display.indexOf('none') >= 0)
                {
                    document.getElementById(indexinput + i.toString()).value = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById(indexinput + i.toString()).value = count;

                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
```

The new array has the correct current order of the list items.
I would love to know how Array.from() does that magic.