# How to display value of objects in vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My code is like this :

```
<script>
    export default {
        props:['search','category','shop'],
        created(){
            ...
        },
        data(){
            return{
                loading:false
            }
        },
        computed:{
            ...
            list:function(){
                console.log(this.$store.state.product);
                return this.$store.state.product.list
            },
        },
        methods:{
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

I do : `console.log(this.$store.state.product);` in list method

Then, I check it on the console

The result is like this :

[image]

I want display value of name

I try like this :

`console.log(this.$store.state.product.list.id.name);`

There exist error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

How can I solve the error?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, This is not a duplicate question. It does not answer my question

Comment: It answers the question above. If that's not your actual question, edit to clarify.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, Seems my question is clear. I tried to like this : `this.$store.state.product.list["12"].name;` and it does not work

Comment: With the information above, that would work. Please update the question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, Try to see the object in the image above. How do I copy the object?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy"?

Comment: I wanted to demonstrate my problem with jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/). So how can I copy object to jsfiddle so you can see my problem

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify` on most objects to get something that you can then use as an object literal in code. So `console.log(JSON.stringify(theObject));` then copy the result from the console. (It may be wrapped in double quotes; if so, don't copy the double quotes.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, When I try on the jsfiddle, It works. But in my project. It does not work. Seems there exist another error. The error : `[Vue warn]: Error when rendering component <search-result-view> at C:\xampp\htdocs\chelseashop\resources\assets\js\components\SearchResultView.vue:`

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder, Seems the error who makes this `this.$store.state.product.list["12"].name;` not working

Comment: I suspect you're running into [this confusing thing about the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection) and that the `product` object's `list` isn't filled in until *later*, after the code where you're trying to do `this.$store.state.product.list["12"].name` has already run. You can prove/disprove that by doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.product));` where you're currently doing `console.log(this.$store.state.product);`.

Comment: (Lurkers: Further debugging by moses toh tells us that this isn't a duplicate of [*Dynamically access object property using variable*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) -- that's *part* of the problem, but not the whole problem.) It's probably a combination of that, plus [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), plus [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection). Fun fun fun.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I'm still confused to solve error `[Vue warn]: Error when rendering component <search-result-view> at C:\xampp\htdocs\chelseashop\resources\assets\js\components\S‌​earchResultView.vue: `. Sorry, my english is not so good. So I find it difficult to understand what you mean

Comment: That error doesn't tell us much of anything, I'm afraid. You'll have to create an [mcve] (each of those -- M, C, and V -- are equally important), replicating the error, and post it to the question (or really, at this point, I would delete this question, thoroughly review the three questions and answers I linked above, debug further, and post an MCVE to a new question if you can't resolve it).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, Ok. I will make a new question. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `list` is an object, with the keys being the different element id's - you are currently trying to access like this:

```
this.$store.state.product.list.id.name
```

You are getting that error because there is no `id` key in the list object, you need to replace `.id` with the actual id value, like this:

```
this.$store.state.product.list["12"].name; //"Bunga Gandeng"
```

Comment: It does not work. There exist error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: What does `Object.keys(this.$store.state.product.list)` give you?

Comment: so `"12"` is a valid key, what does `this.$store.state.product.list["12"]` give you?

Comment: Yes. It give me. The result : https://postimg.org/image/u990r84i1/. But when call name like this : `console.log(this.$store.state.product.list["12"].name);` or `console.log(this.$store.state.product.list[12].name);`, There exist error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`