# React - Cannot read property X of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I am trying to call the string in **section1.text**... My console returns:

[image]

Here is my JSX:

```
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.article.title}</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.article.subTitle}</h2>
                <h3>{this.props.article.body.section1.text}</h3>
            </div>
        );
```

**Both title and subTitle return fine**... but when I try and get the section1.text it returns:

> Cannot read property 'section1' of undefined

I looked online and I think it has something to do with it being a nested object, yet I cant get around my problem. Any suggestions?

---

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance?

Comment: My guess is that the object doesn't have `body` as of when it's being rendered, but it gets added to it *later*, and you're falling afoul of [`console`'s deferred evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection) which is tricking you into thinking `body` is there.

Comment: Is it `this.props.article.body` or `this.props.article.article.body`?

Comment: @KoalaYeung: In that case, he'd be getting the problem on `this.props.article.title`.

Comment: I am declaring a connect variable from my redux store using 'store.article.article' and then calling its attributes in my jsx with 'this.props.article.subTitle' @KoalaYeung

Comment: Like I said, it returns title and subTitle with NO problems, I think the problem lies in how I am calling body.section1.text it within my JSX

Comment: Did you map `article` with `mapStateToProps` in your `connect` call?

Comment: All I have used is @connect((store) => {
    return {article: store.article.article, fetching: store.article.fetching};
})

Comment: @KoalaYeung see above

Comment: Did you try `console.log(this.props.article)` in your render function? The error seems to state that `this.props.article.body` is `undefined`. What is the structure of `article` that is actually received in render?

Comment: (P.S. Last time I encountered similar issue, I had a typo in my code.)

Comment: I agree with @T.J.Crowder. Your console output isn't guaranteed to reflect your `props` on initial render. It can actually update in the meantime, unless you specifically console that property and not the tree. Do your console.log and then immediately after add a line: `debugger`. This will ensure that the output in the console doesn't change. OR do `console.log(this.props.article.body)`. What do you see?

Comment: I logged the article.body on render, it still returns the properties correctly @Chris

Comment: @KoalaYeung the console log image I attached in the question is the result of  redux's fetched data from my sever, like I said, it returns all my other properties fine, just not the ones nested deeper in the objects.

Comment: @danjonescidtrix we can't find the problem without more code. But from what I get from your code above, is that you are returning a loader till the fetch is done, right? and then you are showing the article. In that case I would suggest to share your initial state of the reducer, if the body is there, then it will never be undefined. In that case, share your action and reducer.

Comment: The react debugger output does not help figure out why props.article.body went undefined. I suggested to directly add a console.log statement into your component's render function. That is not what displayed in your image at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Chrome and the "React Tools" Chrome Extension to inspect the state of your component at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Is finally text shown on page? If yes I suspect that Your initial state has no **section1** field, so before first render it's empty.
I had similar issue and this is outcome from my case, maybe Yours is same :)