# javascript, object's attribute miss in console.log

Tags: javascript

You can see that I use console.log to print the object "comment", and you found there is an attribute "text" in "comment._ps", but when I use console.log to print the object "comment._ps", the attribute "text" is missing.
  I don't know why, waiting for help~~

```
console.log(comment);
console.log(comment._ps);
```

[image]

Comment: show your full code

Comment: expand it to check

Comment: what output of `console.log(comment._ps.text);`?

Comment: THX TJ, there is a good answer here .      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/console-log-of-element-children-shows-0-length-but-has-three-entries-when-expand