# javascript object available ourside for loop but undefinded inside for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I got a question here.
I got an object (usrobj) after parsing a JSON object from ajax

```
console.log(usrobj.available[0]);
```

where usrobj.available is an array

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:{currency: "ETH", amount: "0.5"}
1:{currency: "BTC", amount: null}
length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
```

This results a vardump like this

```
{currency: "ETH", amount: "0.5"}
amount:"0.5"
currency:"ETH"
__proto__:Object
```

However when I try to loop through the

```
for(i = 0; i < usrobj.available.length; ++i) {
    $('#assets-table').append('<tr>\
      <td>'+usrobj.available[i].currency+'</td>\
      <td>Available: '+usrobj.available[i].amount+' (Frozen: '+usrobj.frozen[i].amount+')<br /></td>\
...removed for brevity...
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
at Object.success (readAssets.js:22)
at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

could anyone please advise me if they are in different scope? and how do i fix this problem?

Comment: It's probable that you're attempting to use the data before it's retrieved. Try putting the append loop code in the callback part of your ajax request.

Comment: maybe the problem is in the `usrobj.frozen[i]` part, since you did not test it in your snippet ?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). As @zfrisch said, you're probably trying to use the object before it's been filled in, and are getting fooled by [this console behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection). (Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(usrobj.available[0]));`)

Comment: Thanks! It is true that frozen is not definded. And Thanks for the ajax explanation part too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object doesnt have the "frozen" property

"usrobj.frozen[i].amount" so it crash

If usrobj.frozen has in the same position the same value than usrobj.avaiable you will need something like:

```
let usrobj = {
  available: [
    {currency: "ETH", amount: "0.5"},
    {currency: "BTC", amount: null},
  ],
  frozen: [
    null,
    {ammount: '10'}
  ]
}

  for(let i in usrobj.available){
    console.log(
      `Avaiable ${usrobj.available[i].amount}
      Frozen ${(usrobj.frozen && usrobj.frozen[0] && usrobj.frozen[0].amount) || 0}
      `)
  }
```

Comment: I'd say that too, but you can't state that the object does not have the frozen property, since we don't know the shape of `usrobj`, we only have a guess of the shape of `usrobj.available`

Answer (score 0):

as you are running the code **usrobj.available[i].currency** inside the jquery append function,try saving the **this** reference to a variable outside the jquery function and access **usrobj.available[i].currency** inside the append function using **ref.usrobj.available[i].currency**

```js
for(i = 0; i < usrobj.available.length; ++i) {
    let ref = this;
    $('#assets-table').append('<tr>\
      <td>'+ref.usrobj.available[i].currency+'</td>')
 ....     
}
```

it is just a small snippet ,try it

Comment: Not necessary. The global scope is still the global scope and you don't need to reference it to get to the variable at hand.