# Array length is 1 but array[0] is undefined in javascript why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am calling function which returns canvas's array like

```
captureToBlobs(tab, function (blobs) {
   console.log(blobs); // print array perfectly
   console.log(blobs[0]); // print undefined
})
```

first console.log is printing my array correctly but when i am trying to print array[0] then it will be undefined i don't understand why this is happening

Comment: can you please show what blobs result look like, may be it's not an array but an object

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question for us to help you, but you're probably running into this [*console.log of element.children shows 0 length but has three entries when expanded later*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection) Which is one of the many reasons not to stumble around in the dark with a `console.log` torch. Instead, *turn on the lights* by using the debugger.

Comment: the console lies ... try `console.log(JSON.stringify(blobs));`

Comment: It's possible your first console log doesn't print the array "perfectly". The console logging is lazily evaluated, so if you print an object, then *add stuff* to it, and *finally* expand it in the console, you'd get the latest state, not whatever it was at the time of printing.

Comment: Are you sure that your blobs is not an array-like object, which maybe does not have 0 key?

Comment: you are right @T.J.Crowder it will be like your provided link thank you:)

Comment: @RahulDudharejiya - Good deal, glad that helped. Probably best to delete the question; but if you prefer, you can vote to close the question as a duplicate of the one I linked to instead. Happy coding!

Comment: I'm able to log the response value after set timeout function, but still unable to utilise the response outside the scope any suggestions about the same ?? @T.J.Crowder