# How to traverse an Object in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that receives an Object which looks like the following one,

```
Object(12)

0: "UQ"

1: "YTL"

2: "VZW"

3: "LGT"

4: "KDDI"

5: "KT"

6: "SPRINT_T"

7: "RIL"

8: "SKT"
​
9: "SPRINT"
​
10: "KPS"
​
11: "GLB1"
```

and assigned it to variable name is results: string [];

now I traverse the whole array using forEach but I can't. Then I print the length of the object that shows 0.

But I can access the name using results[0] or results[1]. But I can't use loop.

Now, How can I traverse the whole Object and access all names like 'UK', 'YTL'.

Comment: You may be running into [the console's deferred evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection). If not, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Can you add the object declaration? There's not much to go by here. You could try `Object.values` maybe

Comment: When I print that Object in consoles it produces that 12 results. Is it ok for a clear explanation? and I can't use Object.values also @nbokmans

Comment: Is there some specific reason why you can't use `Object.values`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object.keys(). Since this is not an Array but an Object, you cannot use forEach.

```
Object.keys(myObject)
    .sort((x, y) => x >= y ? 1 : -1) // for order preserving, can be omitted if order doesn't matter
    .forEach(key => {
       const value = myObject[key];
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript, you can assign json data in two ways.

1. assign the object as it was:

Suppose, you store json data in a variable name, data. Then you can assign it as it was.

```
data: string[];
this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(
      (data: string[]) => {
        this.data = data;
});
```

And in this way, you can use Foreach or what you expect from this question.

2. Another way to assign using brackets like the following way:

And in this way, you assign that json data as an object which you showed on your question.

```
data: string[];
this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(
      (data: string[]) => {
        this.data = {... data };
});
```

In your problem, you have to use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example by `TypeScript` to traverse an object and get all the terminal nodes, hope it helps:

#### terminal-node.ts:

```
function getCurrentLevelTerminalNodes(obj: any, maxDepth = 100) {
  if (maxDepth <= 0) {
    throw new Error('Too deep to traverse!');
  }

  const res: any[] = [];

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(value => {
    if (typeof obj[value] !== 'object') {
      res.push(obj[value]);
    } else {
      res.push(...getCurrentLevelTerminalNodes(obj[value], maxDepth - 1));
    }
  });

  return res;
}

export default function getTerminalNodes(obj: Object) {
  return getCurrentLevelTerminalNodes(obj);
}
```

#### test case:

```
import getTerminalNodes from './terminal-node';

describe('terminal-node', () => {
  it('get all terminal nodes', () => {
    const testObj = {
      a: {
        b: {
          c: 'c',
        },
      },
      b: 'b',
    };

    expect(getTerminalNodes(testObj)).toStrictEqual(['c', 'b']);
  });
});
```