# JS reference array object what am I doing wrong?arra

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to reference a props array in React via JS. Here is the array output called "selectedProps" as per console.log:

```
[0: {selectedSeverity: "warning", selectedDomain: "JUNIPER"}]
```

I am trying to access selectedSeverity by calling selectedProps[0].selectedSeverity but am getting an error. I know this should be easy but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: *"...but am getting an error."* ***What*** error? Also, what you've shown as the output of `console.log` doesn't look like anything I've seen in the console -- it's using `[]` as for an array, but also `0:` which is property notation. (But if it were an array of objects, your code for accessing the property would be correct.) Please double-check what's being output, ideally using the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser (rather than `console.log`).

Comment: Really guessing here, but it *could* be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection

Comment: removed 0: first item is at index 0 anyway so selectedProps[0].selectedSeverity should work after removed 0:

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very active place. When you post a question (or an answer), please *stick around* so you can clarify anything that comes up in the comments.

Comment: Sorry T.J. I had a family emergency to attend to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your array is malformed.  Try this:

```
var selectedProps = [{0: {selectedSeverity: "warning", selectedDomain: "JUNIPER"}}]
```

Then access a property like:

```
selectedProps[0][0].selectedSeverity
```

Note that this is a little odd because you are naming a property key 0 and that is also how you access the first element in the array.  Consider changing your object declartion to something like:

```
 var selectedProps = [{info : {selectedSeverity: "warning", selectedDomain: "JUNIPER"}}]
```

Then you access it like:

```
selectedProps[0].info.selectedSeverity
```

Comment: The OP didn't say that was in their code, they said that's what they see via `console.log`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder first sentence: "I am trying to reference a props array "

Comment: The array is malformed and will result in an error in the console.  Try it yourself

Comment: Yes, I'm [*tolerably* familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers) with basic JavaScript syntax. The point is that the OP said that's the output of `console.log`, **not** something in their code. So clearly, whatever it is they logged actually exists. Until/unless they clarify what it actually is (since it obviously isn't what they've shown), it's impossible to answer the question. (I suspect what they really *already have* is what you've told them to *change* it to, but we can't know.)

Comment: console.log is user code.  odd to down-vote this given the ambiguity since no matter what, whatever is being logged is malformed.

Comment: Don't assume the people commenting and the people voting are the same people. You'll be wrong more often than right. I can't make out what you're trying to say with this malformed thing -- you can't log something that doesn't exist, and you can't create something with "malformed" syntax. But that's okay, I don't need to understand what you mean. If/when the OP comes back, hopefully one of us will be able to help him/her.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help with this.

Comment: Hello I just wanted to say thank you again for your help and info with this. I got flagged because of my lack of responsiveness with regards to this question and don't want to abuse or misuse this excellent site. Everyone here is so helpful and I am relatively new to the programming side of things and I do so appreciate everyone's help. I'm sorry that I did not adequately follow up with this.

Comment: @CHays412 what was the solution?  If this was the correct or most helpful answer can you please make a comment and accept it as the solution?