# Component not re-rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, I've looked at many questions on here similar to this and cannot find a solution. Basically in my App.js, I have two buttons to change `this.state.language` between english(en) and spanish(es). When I would hard code the language state it would work. (I get the language data via a JSON file).

Now however, when i try to use the two buttons, the state changes(verified via console log) but the language on the page doesn't update. On the page below I have an if statement to detect the language state and from there pick from where in the JSON file to get the data from. Please can someone explain to me why this is not working?

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sideNav: '',
      language: ''
    }
    this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
    this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);
  }

  langEn() {
    this.setState({language: 'en'});
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  langEs() {
    this.setState({language: 'es'});
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {

    const mouseEnter = e => {
      this.setState({sideNav: "sideNav sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---expanded---1KdUL"});
    }    

    const mouseLeave = e => {
      this.setState({sideNav: "sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---collapsed---LQDEv"});
    }


    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <div>
          <SideNav 
            onMouseEnter={mouseEnter} 
            onMouseLeave={mouseLeave}
            className={this.state.sideNav}
            onSelect={(selected) => {
                // Add your code here
            }}
          >
            <SideNav.Nav  defaultSelected="home">
                <NavItem eventKey="home">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/"><img src={Dash}/></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="sites">
                    <NavIcon>
                      <Link to="/sites"><img src={Site} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/sites">Sites</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="tours">
                  <NavIcon>
                    <Link to="/tours"><img src={Tour}/></Link>
                  </NavIcon>
                  <NavText>
                      <Link to="/tours">Tours</Link>
                  </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="media">
                    <NavIcon>
                      <Link to="/media"><img src={Media}/> </Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/media">Media</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="newSite">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/newSite/details"><img src={NewSite} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/newSite/details">Add new Site</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="language">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/language"><img src={Lang} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/language">Language</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="profile">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/profile"><img src={Profile} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>

            </SideNav.Nav>
            <button onClick={this.langEn}>EN</button>
            <button onClick={this.langEs}>ES</button>
          </SideNav>
        </div>
        <Routes childProps={this.state} />
      </div>
    );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

The page I want to be translated:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Col, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import './NewForm.css';
import data from '../data.json';


class NewFormDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            language: '',
            siteName: '',
            counties: '',
            siteAddress: '',
            siteEmail: '',
            siteNumber: '',
            siteCat: '',
            openTimes: '',
            fees: '',
            access: '',
            gps: '',
            w3w: '',
            txtHeader: '',
            txtContent: ''
        };

    }

    validateForm() {
        if (this.state.siteName != '' &&
            this.state.siteAddress != '' &&
            this.state.siteEmail != '' &&
            this.state.siteNumber != '' &&
            this.state.openTimes != '' && 
            this.state.fees != '' && 
            this.state.access != '' && 
            this.state.gps != '' && 
            this.state.w3w != '' && 
            this.state.txtHeader != '' && 
            this.state.txtContent != '') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        this.props.history.push('/newSite/tours');
    }

    render() {

        this.setState({language: this.props.language});

        let jsonLang;

        if (this.state.language == 'en') {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        } else if (this.state.language == 'es') {
            jsonLang = data.es;
        } else {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        }

        this.placeholders = jsonLang.placeholders;
        this.counties = jsonLang.counties;
        this.categories = jsonLang.categories;
        console.log(this.state.language)

        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
                {/* General Information */}
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="siteName" id="siteName" placeholder={this.placeholders.siteName}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input className="form-control" type="select" id="counties" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option className="selectDefault" disabled value={this.placeholders.siteCounties} selected>{this.placeholders.siteCounty}</option>
                            { this.counties.map(c => (<option key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.display}</option>))}
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea" onChange={this.handleChange} name="siteAddress" placeholder={this.placeholders.siteAdd} id="siteAddress" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="email" name="siteEmail" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteEmail" placeholder={this.placeholders.email} />
                    </Col> 
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="tel" name="siteNumber" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteNumber" placeholder={this.placeholders.number}/>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="select" name="siteCat" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteCat" multiple placeholder={this.placeholders.categories}>
                            <option className="selectDefault" disabled selected>{this.placeholders.categories}</option>
                            { this.categories.map(c => (<option key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.display}</option>))}
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="openTimes" onChange={this.handleChange} id="openTimes" placeholder={this.placeholders.times} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="fees" onChange={this.handleChange} id="fees" placeholder={this.placeholders.fees}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="access" onChange={this.handleChange} id="access" placeholder={this.placeholders.access} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <hr/>
                {/* Location Information */}
                <FormGroup row> 
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="gps" onChange={this.handleChange} id="gps" placeholder={this.placeholders.gps}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="w3w" id="w3w" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder={this.placeholders.w3w} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <hr/>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="txtHeader" onChange={this.handleChange} id="txtHeader" placeholder={this.placeholders.textHeader} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="txtContent" onChange={this.handleChange} id="txtContent" placeholder={this.placeholders.textContent} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check row>
                    <Col sm={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}>
                        <Button disabled={!this.validateForm()} type="submit" className="btn-primary">Tours &rarr;</Button>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup> 
            </Form>
        );
    }
  }

  export default withRouter(NewFormDetails);
```

Comment: Other than having `console.log` immediately after `setState` (which is a no-no, state updates are *asynchronous*, the reason it seems to work is [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection)), the `langEn`/`langEs` part seems fine. Please update your question with a [mcve] (note the "Minimal") demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: The component (`App`) where you're setting `this.state.language` never uses `this.state.language` at all.

Comment: You are not using `this.state.languages` in `render()`.

Comment: Side note: The `if`/`else if`/`else` structure you're using to get `data.en` or `data.es` can be simplified to: `jsonLang = data[this.state.language] || data.en;`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What do you mean? App doesn't need to use it, it just gets set there

Comment: @TiernO - State is specific to the component. Setting state in a component that you never use in that component does nothing. There is nothing magically connecting `this.state.language` in `App` to `NewFormDetails`'s `props.language` or `this.state.language`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see what you mean, the reason I wanted it to be on App.js is because the App component contains the side navbar which is on every page. Thats why I want the select language to be there

Comment: @TiernO - It's fine to do it that way (the classic [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)), but then `App` needs to pass on `language` to any components that need it via props. Another option is to use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have passed it via props tho. I've edited the question to show what I've attempted in `NewFormDetails`

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder already mentioned in his first comment. `this.setState`is **asynchronous** which means that it might not be called and executed directly. Moreover you should never call `this.setState()` inside the render method. Use `this.props.language` in your if-statement as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `App` never uses `this.state.language` and doesn't pass it on to any other components.

If you want the language set at the `App` level, you have at least two options:

1. Use state and pass `language` to components that need it via props (the classic [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)).
2. Use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
3. I'm sure there's a third option using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), but I haven't gotten into hooks yet.

Quick example of #1:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            language: "en"
        };
        this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
        this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);
    }
    langEs() {
        this.setState({language: "es"});
    }
    langEn() {
        this.setState({language: "en"});
    }
    render() {
        const {language} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.langEn}>English</button>
                <button onClick={this.langEs}>Español</button>
                <Thingy language={language} />
                <Whatsit language={language} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Thingy extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {language} = this.props;
        return <div>Thingy's language is {language}</div>;
    }
}

const Whatsit = props => (
  <div>Whatsit's language is {props.language}</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Quick example of #2:

```js
const LangContext = React.createContext("en");

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            language: "en"
        };
        this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
        this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);
    }
    langEs() {
        this.setState({language: "es"});
    }
    langEn() {
        this.setState({language: "en"});
    }
    render() {
        const {language} = this.state;
        return (
            <LangContext.Provider value={language}>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.langEn}>English</button>
                    <button onClick={this.langEs}>Español</button>
                    <Thingy />
                    <Whatsit />
                </div>
            </LangContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

class Thingy extends React.Component {
    static contextType = LangContext;
    render() {
        const language = this.context;
        return <div>Thingy's language is {language}</div>;
    }
}

class Whatsit extends React.Component {
    static contextType = LangContext;
    render() {
        const language = this.context;
        return <div>Whatsit's language is {language}</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I need to work on making the language remain what it was when I swap pages haha

Comment: @TiernO - For that, you might store it in `localStorage` and load it from `localStorage` in `App`'s constructor. [More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned in the comments you are not using `this.state.language` inside your `render()` method of `NewFormDetails`. React will only rerender components when a new state actually has impact in the `render()` method.

Since you're just using it inside your constructor react won't rerender your component. Simply move your if-else statement to the render method and you should be fine.

EDIT:

You're copying `this.props.language` to your components state but you're not changing the state afterwards. `this.props.language` changes on the outside but those changes are not reflected inside the component. You should access `this.props.lanugage` directly inside your `render()` method.

```
if (this.props.language == 'en') {
  ...
}
```

Or is there a reason you copy it to the state?

Comment: I moved the following `let jsonLang;
  
        if (this.state.language == 'en') {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        } else if (this.state.language == 'es') {
            jsonLang = data.es;
        } else {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        }
  
        this.placeholders = jsonLang.placeholders;
        this.counties = jsonLang.counties;
        this.categories = jsonLang.categories;
        console.log(this.state.language)` to the render() method and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that you get the language from the props and set the translated string in the constructor of NewFormDetails. When you click the buttons to change language, NewFormDetails just updated and needn't excute constructor function, so the strings are old strings. **I think you can get language from props in render function and  set set the strings in render function too.**