# Why is there a difference between the views I've included as images?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, data-structures

(I have edited the question to describe it more clearly and short.)

Why there is a key as `20.42` when expending but it not presented in the folded view(in the red circle).
See screenshot below, It's weird that there is one index of the array is `20.42` in expended view.

It happened on this situation:

1. I use `push` method to add element to an empty array.
2. Then `console.log` the array.
3. Did some assign `20.42` to the array by mistake.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] that illustrates the behavior where `push` results in this structure? Arrays are objects, and object property keys are just strings, so this is quite possible to see, just quite weird (probably indicative of broken code)

Comment: @AlanWang  yes it's possible as JS array are objects with length property

Comment: Are you asking a question about Arrays in general (i.e. how can *any* Array have an index that is not an integer)? Or, are you asking how this specific Array have a property/index that is not an integer (i.e. that is `20.42`)?

Comment: @AlanWang Your English is good. It is certainly better than I would be in your native language. Your question is better than many that are asked by native English speakers. However, what you are wanting to know is not clear to me. I can see a few different possible interpretations of what you ask. For example: A) "How did this happen in my code?" B) "How can such indexes exist in Arrays in general?" or C) "Why is there a difference between the views I've included as images?" For B, the answers below can cover it. For A and C, we are going to need more information from you (e.g. your code).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript arrays are objects that assign special behavior to properties whose names are array indexes (strings that convert to integers in a given range¹), have a special `length` property, and are backed by `Array.prototype`. They're still objects, which means they can have properties whose entries *aren't* array indexes, too:

```js
const a = [];
a[0] = "zero, normal array entry";
a[20.42] = "20.42, normal object property, not an array entry";
console.log(a);
```

```html
Look in the real console
```

Both `0` and `20.42` above are (in specification terms) converted to string and used as property names. (The JavaScript engine can and will optimize that when you're dealing with normal array indexes.)

So somewhere, your code is assigning a `BigNumber` to the property name `"20.42"`.

---

¹ From the spec:

> An *integer index* is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see [7.1.16](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-canonicalnumericindexstring)) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 2<sup>53</sup> - 1. An *array index* is an integer index whose numeric value i is in the range +0 ≤ i < 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.

Comment: Wait, why doesn't anything show up in the Stack Snippet console? What black magic is this?

Comment: OK, got it, you ticked "don't show console"...

Comment: @VLAZ - The snippet console does an `Array.isArray` test and, if it's an array, only shows array elements, not all the properties of an object. So I disabled the snippet console to avoid confusion. :-) *Edit:* Yes, that's right.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I just forgot that option existed. I thought that somehow merely having the `20.42` key broke the console or something :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how can i disable console here ?

Comment: @CodeManiac there is a tick box on the left side when you're making a snippet. (I had to copy the snippet and edit it to actually notice it). It adds a `console: false` to the beginning of the snippet.

Comment: But I only use .push method to add elements to an empty array. Then console.log it. never assign it. I'm trying to reproduce it. We can see '20.42' as a key in the folded view() is your example. But look at my second picture as a compare, the folded view, there is not a key as '20.42'.

Comment: @AlanWang As [I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390294/why-js-array-index-has-a-decimal/56390347?noredirect=1#comment99380195_56390388), `push` will never create a property like that. Something in your code **is** creating that property -- by direct assignment (most likely), by `Object.assign`, *something*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Really thank you, It's weird there is no key as `20.42` in folded view(in my second picture). Answers that using assign, there is a key as `20.42` in folded view, in my question's third picture.

Comment: @AlanWang - The "folded view" doesn't show keys, how do you know 20.42 isn't there? But in any case, that view is a snapshot of the array as it was when it was logged. When you expand the array, you get its contents *as of when you expanded* it, so it's not unusual that they don't match. (That's what the little "i" in a blue circle tells you if you hover it.) [Details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, `When you expand the array, you get its contents as of when you expanded it`, maybe that's the reason. But The "folded view" should show keys if it has(compare my second and third picture)

Comment: @AlanWang - What I get from those screenshots is that the console adjusts its initial display based on how many entries are in the array and perhaps even on what their values are. Rather than concentrating on that display, which is at best a tangent, I would focus on the code, searching for the bit that is clearly creating a `"20.42"` property on your array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get a decimal.

[image]

Its not the index btw. The console.log output and the array length property says it all. Still confused? You need to revisit basic JavaScript programming.

Comment: You can create a code snippet here which will makes answer more readable, read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: But I only use `.push` method to add elements to an empty array. Then console.log it. never assign it. I'm trying to reproduce it.

Comment: @double-beep My intent here was not to paste some executable code but to show how something is displayed by the browser's console.

Comment: @AlanWang there must be something which is causing this behaviour. As I showed you in the example above. Its quite possible even if by mistake.

Comment: We can see '2.2' as a key in the folded view(). Look at my second picture， the folded view, there is not a key as '20.42'.

Comment: @AlanWang - `push` will never create these properties. Something somewhere in your code **is** doing direct assignment on `arr`.

Comment: @AlanWang, this is some weird behaviour of the browser console I guess. Have you tried replicating it in different browsers?