# How to pass an object as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I am having troubles with some parts of my code randomly.

This object is declared in a `angular controller`.

```
this.tData = {
   'questions':[],
   'typeQuestion':[],
   'category':[],
   'dName':this.dName,
   'tCodigo':this.tCodigo}
```

Then I got some data from others functions and push it into respective fields,

```
this.tData.questions.push(this.idQuestion) // this come from frontend ng-model
this.tData.typeQuestion.push(this.typeQuest) // this come from frontend ng-model
this.tData.category.push(this.idCategory)// this come from frontend ng-model
```

This construct my object fine. Doing `console.log(this.tData)` show me the object completely fine. But then when I pass it to the backend in this function of the `angular service`.

```
this.updateStuff = function(codStuff,tData){
 return $http.put('/updateStuff' + codStuff,tData)}
```

The object that backend get doing `console.log(params)` is

```
{
 questions:['exampleId'],
typeQuestion:['exampleData'],
category:[], // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
dName:'exampleName',
tCodigo:'exampleCod'}
```

Like you see `category:[]` is empty but doing `console.log(tData)` in the service of `angular` before I send it I see the correct data there.
I miss data when I send it to the backend. This problem happend to me in 3 others cases like this.

Why some arrays are ok in backend and why others are not?

I tried a lot of things but ever 1 item of the object I send to the backend go empty.

If you need more specific code tell me in comments.

## Updates

Code here I push category in the controller:

```
this.getCategoryByName = function(){
  this.bName = document.getElementById('seCategory').value;
  Category.getCategoryByName(this.bName).then((result)=>{
    this.idCategory = result.data.data._id; // this give me id of category
    this.tData.category.push(this.idCategory);
  })
  }
```

## 2

This is where I call in frontend my functions:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctController.getCategoryByName(); ctController.updateTest();" > up </button>
```

This is the code of updateTest() function:

```
this.updateTest = function(){
Test.updateTest(this.codTest,this.tData).then(result=>{})
}
```

Above method call the `angular service` `updateStuff`

## SOLVED

Solved adding a chain promise in the method getCategoryByName and adding the updateTest() method nested in getCategoryByName() method  more or less like  @T.J. Crowder sugest so I give it the response.

Comment: See [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection). Don't stumble around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, *turn on the lights* using the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE. Set a breakpoint on the call to `this.updateStuff`. When the breakpoint is hit, look at `this.tData.category`. You'll almost certainly see that it is empty.

Comment: Good advice (I will use a debbuger), I added a breakpoint int $http.put but still seeing complete object.

Comment: But was that one of the times when the backend said `category` was empty? *That's* the case you need to catch. I'm quite sure `$http.put` isn't broken, so either A) What you're passing it doesn't have anything in `category`, or B) Your backend code is messing up what it receives.

Comment: I think backend isnt the problem. I test it using postman and all okay, so problem is frontend. But still cant get the problem, gonna debugg all methods.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Instead of `return $http.put('/updateStuff' + codStuff,tData)}` you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(tData));` to capture what's in `tData` as of when `updateStuff` is called. I don't think we can help you more without one. (For myself, I'm certain that `updateStuff` is [still being called before `getCategoryByName` is done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56442543/157247).)  Good luck!

Comment: I will recheck all what you told me in this post, next days will update if I found the solution. Ty for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Code here I push category in the controller:
>
> ```
> this.getCategoryByName = function(){
>   this.bName = document.getElementById('seCategory').value;
>   Category.getCategoryByName(this.bName).then((result)=>{
>     this.idCategory = result.data.data._id; // this give me id of category
>     this.tData.category.push(this.idCategory);
>   })
>   }
> ```

That tells us that you're calling `updateStuff` before `Category.getCategoryByName` has finished its work, and so **before** `this.tData.category.push` is called. The reason `console.log` *seems* to show you things in `this.tData.category` is (as I mentioned in a comment) because of [deferred evaluation in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440788/missing-data-when-i-pass-an-object-as-a-parameter?noredirect=1#comment99474916_56440788).

This also explains why it happens *sometimes*: You have a race between that `Category.getCategoryByName` operation and the operation calling `updateStuff`. Sometimes, `Category.getCategoryByName` wins and so `updateStuff` includes the pushed information, other times the code calling `updateStuff` wins and so `updateStuff` doesn't have the information in `this.tDate.category` (yet).

`this.getCategoryByName` should return the promise chain:

```
    this.getCategoryByName = function(){
      this.bName = document.getElementById('seCategory').value;
      return Category.getCategoryByName(this.bName).then((result)=>{
//    ^^^^^^
        this.idCategory = result.data.data._id; // this give me id of category
        this.tData.category.push(this.idCategory);
      });
    };
```

...and then you should make whatever is calling `updateStuff` dependent on the resolution of that promise.

(You'll also want to ensure that something handles the chain's rejection path. Your current `getCategoryByName` ignores errors, which will lead to "Unhandled rejection" errors in the console if `Category.getCategoryByName` fails.)

Comment: @Schwarz54 - Are you **sure** you made the call to `updateStuff` wait?