# Objects in array are empty when return statement is included in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a function that I want to return the array of objects `parsedContacts`. With the return statement there, the `console.log` above it prints an array of empty objects. When I remove the return statement, each object has three properties as expected.

How can I return the `parsedContacts` and include the properties?

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

export const getAndProcessPhoneContacts = async () => {
  PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
    {
      'title': 'Contacts',
      'message': 'Xxxxxxxx would like to view your contacts.'
    }
  )
  const contacts = await getContacts();
  const parsedContacts = parseContacts(contacts);
  sortContacts(parsedContacts);
  console.log(parsedContacts);
  return parsedContacts; // this line needs to be removed for parsedContacts to have properties in the objects inside it.
}

const getContacts = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Contacts.getAll((error, contacts) => {
      contacts ? resolve(contacts) : reject(error)
    })
  })
}

const parseContacts = contacts => {
  return contacts.map(contact => {
    let parsedContact = {}
    Object.keys(contact).forEach(key => {
      switch (key) {
        case 'givenName':
          parsedContact.firstName = contact[key]
          break
        case 'familyName':
          parsedContact.surname = contact[key]
          break
        case 'phoneNumbers':
          parsedContact.phoneNumber = contact[key].length ? contact[key][0].number : ''
      }
    })
    return parsedContact
  })
}

const sortContacts = contacts => {
  contacts.sort((a, b) => {
    let contactA = a.firstName;
    let contactB = b.firstName;
    return (contactA < contactB) ? -1 : (contactA > contactB) ? 1 : 0;
  });
}
```

## Update

As requested in the comments below, here is the calling function of `getAndProcessPhoneContacts`. I know that this is ugly and needs refactoring, any advice on this gratefully accepted too!

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    ConnectyCube.init(...config)
    try {
      const accessToken = await getFirebaseToken();
      if (accessToken) {
        await authorizeConnectyCube(accessToken);
        if (this.props.user.parsedContacts) {
          const registeredUsers = await retrieveRegisteredUsers();
          this.props.updateRegisteredContacts(registeredUsers);
          Actions.Dashboard();
        } else {
          const parsedContacts = await getParsedContactsFromStorage();
          if (parsedContacts) {
            this.props.updateParsedContacts(parsedContacts);
            Actions.Dashboard();
          } else {
            const parsedContacts = await getAndProcessPhoneContacts();
            console.log(parsedContacts); // prints an array of empty objects
            await writeParsedContactsToStorage(parsedContacts);
            this.props.updateParsedContacts(parsedContacts);
            const registeredUsers = await retrieveRegisteredUsers();
            this.props.updateRegisteredContacts(registeredUsers);
            Actions.Dashboard();
          }
        }
      } else {
        Actions.PhoneNumberInput();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error);
    }
  }
```

## Update 2

I have an inelegant solution by using a callback:

```
            const cb = (ct) => {
              console.log(ct); // Objects now have properties
            }
            const parsedContacts = await getAndProcessPhoneContacts(cb);
            await writeParsedContactsToStorage(parsedContacts);
            this.props.updateParsedContacts(parsedContacts);
            const registeredUsers = await retrieveRegisteredUsers();
            this.props.updateRegisteredContacts(registeredUsers);
            Actions.Dashboard();
          }
        }
      } else {
        Actions.PhoneNumberInput();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error);
    }
  }
```

And the called function:

```
export const getAndProcessPhoneContacts = async (cb) => {
  PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
    {
      'title': 'Contacts',
      'message': 'Xxxxxxx would like to view your contacts.'
    }
  )
  const contacts = await getContacts();
  const parsedContacts = parseContacts(contacts);
  sortContacts(parsedContacts);
  console.log(parsedContacts);
  cb(parsedContacts)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display the object as in json format ?

Comment: No, as is is fine.

Comment: How do you know the object has the fields when you remove the console.log? Are you attaching a debugger?

Comment: With the code shown, the `return` statement you refer to **cannot** affect the content of `parsedContacts` unless whatever is receiving it is mucking with it...which could well be what's going on, actually, given [this "feature" of consoles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection). So we need to see the code using the result of `getAndProcessPhoneContacts`.

Comment: Side note: Your `sort` callback should probably use `localeCompare`, not least because it's simpler: `.sort((a, b) => a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName))`.

Comment: are you sure there are contacts to begin with?

Comment: So now the question is, what does `writeParsedContactsToStorage` do with the array of objects? Fundamentally, you need to update the question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Please be sure to read that link **carefully** before saying you can't do that. (For instance: Yes, you're using React native, but that doesn't mean you can't create an MCVE that doesn't use React native.)

Comment: Ok thanks @T.J.Crowder, I will look at this now. In the meantime, I have successfully passed `parsedContacts` back to the calling function by including a callback as a parameter in `getAndProcessPhoneContacts`, have added to the question..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `writeParsedContactsToStorage` writes the array to local storage on the device.