# Why is Array.indexOf() working correctly with one redux action but not with another? (same reducer)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, indexof

```
var tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5',
            'tag6', 'tag7', 'tag8', 'tag9', 'tag0'];

var selectedTags = [];

const tagsReducer = (state={}, action) => {
    var tagIndex = '';
    if(action.type==="ADD_TAG") {                     //this if statement works as expected
        tagIndex = tags.indexOf(action.payload);
        selectedTags.push(tags[tagIndex]);
        tags.splice(tagIndex, 1);
        return {tags, selectedTags};    
    }
    if(action.type==="REMOVE_TAG"){                          //this doesn't
        tagIndex = selectedTags.indexOf(action.payload);
        console.log(selectedTags);                            //prints the expected array
        console.log(action.payload);                          //prints the expected string
        console.log(tagIndex);                                //prints -1 (doesn't find the string)
        console.log(typeof(selectedTags));                    //prints object
        console.log(typeof(action.payload));                  // prints string
        tags.push(selectedTags[tagIndex]); 
        selectedTags.splice(tagIndex, 1);

        return {tags, selectedTags};
    }
    return {tags, selectedTags}
}
```

The string mathes one of the array items, but the indexOf() function still returns -1. It's confusing because the first action works fine, but the second doesn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: what can be the value of `action.payload`?

Comment: Any string from 'tag0' to 'tag9' depending on which one i want to remove

Comment: If the string is in `selectedTags` *when you run `indexOf`*, `indexOf` **will** find it. :-) So what you need to do is look closely at the `payload.action` and the strings in `selectedTags`. You'll find some difference -- a space at the beginning or end of the string, a slight difference in spelling, a difference in capitalization, etc. But also note [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection) with logging objects and arrays to the console. `selectedTags` may not have the tag in it as of when `indexOf` runs.

Comment: can you post the `console.logs()` of selectedTags and action.payload

Comment: I agree with @T.J.Crowder

Comment: All strings / 'tags' are from the initial array defined as tags. They are added to selectedTags one by one on click, with the first action. So the value of the string can not change. The payload is the same string, but indexOf() doesn't seem to find it. I did the same as in the first action.

Comment: Re your edit *"string mathes one of the array items, but the indexOf() function still returns -1"* It **doesn't** match one of the array items as of when you're calling `indexOf`. `indexOf` [isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). So you need to set aside that belief and see which of the possible alternatives it is: timing, or a difference in the string. (One possible diff I didn't think to note above: primitive strings and String objects are not === to each other, so if one of them [the one in the array or the one in the payload] is a String object... :-) )

Comment: ![Code snap] https://i.ibb.co/FsB2GJV/code.png
![Console snap] https://i.ibb.co/ZhvFDgZ/console.png

Comment: just a suggestion here, rather than using an array use a hashmap to improve efficiency if the number of tags increase.

Comment: @redmaster - There are several ways (see my answer) that the -1 is correct despite those screenshots, see my answer. One of the possibilities I mention there that I haven't in the comments above is a single entry in your array being `"tag1,tag2"`.

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem since the array length is correct every time, i just checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> string mathes one of the array items, but the indexOf() function still returns -1

It **doesn't** match one of the array items as of when you're calling `indexOf`, because if it did, `indexOf` would find it. `indexOf` [isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips).

So that leaves two general possibilities:

1. The string that's in the array looks like it should match, but is *slightly* different from the string in the `payload`. Ways it might be different that may not be obvious:

   - One of them (the one in the array or the one in `payload`) may have a space at the beginning or end, etc.
   - One of them may have a slight difference in capitalization.
   - They may have slightly different characters that are easily confused, like `ç` and `ç`.
   - The entry in the array may have a comma in it, for instance `"thisTag,thatTag"` which won't, of course, match `"thatTag"` if you go looking, although it looks like `"thatTag"` is in the array.
   - One of them may be a `String` object where the other is a string primitive; `String` objects and string primitives are not `===` to each other, and `indexOf` uses a `===` test.
2. The string isn't in the `selectedTags` array as of when you call `indexOf`, even though it looks like it in the console. That's because of [this feature of consoles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection).

To figure it out, set a breakpoint on the `indexOf` line and, when it's hit, look at the string in `payload` and the string in `selectedTags` (if it's there — if not, then it was the console thing). You'll find ***some*** difference.

Comment: Figured it out with redux devTools. It was a leading space after the tag string, i still have to figure out why it gets the variable that way, but the cause of the problem is known. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @redmaster - Glad you found it! About the `ç` and `ç` bullet point above, if these tags are user-entered, you might want to call [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) on them on receipt before storing them (in the array, the data store, etc.) so you're storing and comparing a normalized form. `"Français" === "Français"` is false, but `"Français".normalize() === "Français".normalize()` is true. :-) (Details in Chapter 10 of my book, if you're curious.)

Comment: These are predefined tags, that's why i initialized the array in redux

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your book features looks amazing. I would like to purchase your book. Any plans for paid digital copy of the book?

Comment: @Vishal - Yes, it'll be available as an ebook through the publisher (so, presumably, through Amazon and B&N and such), I don't know the details of that yet. There's no web copy. I'll probably do that with the next one, but I wanted to have at least one good old-fashioned bricks-and-mortar established publisher book under my belt before going the more modern route. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am eagerly waiting for the hard copy to be released. I will order it form Amazon. If you have any requirements for react dev, please let me know. I would love to work with such a knowledgeable guy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are mutiple issue. You are trying to modify the external variable. Which is not pure. First rule of redux, Dont add side effect modifying external data. It has to be pure. The output should be processed data on input data. Below is the sample code. You can refine it later.

```
var tags = [
  "tag1",
  "tag2",
  "tag3",
  "tag4",
  "tag5",
  "tag6",
  "tag7",
  "tag8",
  "tag9",
  "tag0"
];

var selectedTags = [];

const tagsReducer = (state = { tags, selectedTags }, action) => {
  var tagIndex = -1;
  if (action.type === "ADD_TAG") {
    //this if statement works as expected
    tagIndex = state.tags.indexOf(action.payload);
    const data = state.tags[tagIndex];
    return {
      tags: state.tags.filter(x => x !== data),
      selectedTags: state.selectedTags.concat(data)
    };
  }
  if (action.type === "REMOVE_TAG") {
    //this doesn't

    tagIndex = state.selectedTags.indexOf(action.payload);
    const data = state.tags[tagIndex];

    if (data)
      return {
        tags: state.tags,
        selectedTags: selectedTags.filter(x => x !== data)
      };
  }
  return state;
};
```

I tried to create stackblitz, draft also.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-playground-twrxyy?file=index.js