# TypeError: Cannot read property 'rating' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, flux

I'm using React to make call to a back-end API and retrieve an array of JSON objects. I am able to print the array of objects AND the individual objects to the console, but as soon as I try to access the values inside the object I get a Type Error. I'm using the flux framework. Here are my actions:

```
//ratingsActions.js

import dispatcher from "../appDispatcher";
import * as ratingsApi from "../api/ratingsApi";
import actionTypes from "./actionTypes";


export function loadRatings() {
  return ratingsApi.getRatings().then(ratings => {
    dispatcher.dispatch({
      actionType: actionTypes.LOAD_RATINGS,
      ratings: ratings
    });
  });
}
```

And my store:

```
//ratingsStore.js 

import { EventEmitter } from "events";
import Dispatcher from "../appDispatcher";
import actionTypes from "../actions/actionTypes";

const CHANGE_EVENT = "change";
let _ratings = [];

class RatingsStore extends EventEmitter {
  addChangeListener(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  removeChangeListener(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  emitChange() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  }

  getRatings() {
    return _ratings;
  }
}

const store = new RatingsStore();

Dispatcher.register(action => {
  switch (action.actionType) {
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_RATINGS:
      store.emitChange();
      break;
    case actionTypes.LOAD_RATINGS:
      _ratings = action.ratings;
      store.emitChange();
      break;
    default:
  }
});

export default store;
```

```
//component
  const [ratings, setRatings] = useState(ratingsStore.getRatings());

  useEffect(() => {
    ratingsStore.addChangeListener(onChange);
    if (ratingsStore.getRatings().length === 0) loadRatings();
    return () => ratingsStore.removeChangeListener(onChange);
  }, []);

  function onChange() {
    setRatings(ratingsStore.getRatings());
  }

console.log(ratingsStore.getRatings()[0]) ;
```

Now, in my component I try to do `console.log(ratingsStore.getRatings()[0];)` which returns an object as in this image:

[image: json object]

but if i try to do `console.log(ratingsStore.getRatings()[0].rating;)` I get the error as in the subject. What is wrong here??

UPDATE: Ok I'm even more confused now. when I export `window.ratings=ratings` to the browser, I am able to access every field from the objects in the array, for instance `ratings[0].teamName` and it prints to the console. Yet `ratings[0].teamName` still does not work in the application...

Comment: I think you must be trying to do those things at different types. Normally I'd think it was [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection), but that screenshot doesn't fit it and if `_ratings` were empty, you'd get `undefined` in the console instead of an empty object anyway.

Comment: Hi T.J. Crowder, what do you mean by doing those things at different types?

Comment: Heh, sorry -- *times*, not *types*. Typo. :-)

Comment: I see. I have added my `useState` and `useEffect` from the component. Does that help with trying to isolate the timing issue?

Comment: The last line of the code (`console.log(ratingsStore.getRatings()[0]) ;`) is incorrect. There are two problems: 1. It use use `ratings`, not call `ratingsStore.getRatins()`. 2. It needs to allow for the fact that `ratings` may be empty (e.g., if the dispatcher hasn't supplied any ratings yet). I don't use Flux, but I think there are more fundamental issues, it may be worth going through [this tutorial](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc) or similar.

Comment: `if (ratingsStore.getRatings().length === 0) loadRatings();` that line should account for if the storage is empty right? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Yes, but asynchronously. Meanwhile, the code at the end runs, and fails.