# Reactjs - Get Height of a div/image using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to get **Height** of an image in a react functional component using react hooks.

I have used below code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

const DepthChartContent = props => {
  const ref = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref && ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight) {
      console.log('called')
    }
    console.log('useEffect', {
      ref,
      current: ref.current,
      clientHeight: ref.current.clientHeight,
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <img
      ref={ref}
      className="depth-reference-bar"
      src={DepthRuler}
      alt="no ruler found"
    />
  )
}
```

The problem with this is that it returns the clientHeight as 0 but console.log in useEffect has the correct clientHeight as shown in below pic.

[image: ref-console-image]

This means that `ref && ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight` is not defined when called but consoling in same useEffect is showing correct value for `ref`, `current: ref.current` but `clientHeight: ref.current.clientHeight` is ZERO.

Similarly, I can't use `....}, [ref && ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight]` in `useEffect` because `useEffect` do not accept complex expression. If I defined a variable outside or inside `useEffect` as `const clientHeight = (ref && ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight) || 0`, no luck!

Can anyone help in this regards. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try Passinf the ref as dependency of use effect, rather than executing the side effect only on mount?

Comment: P.s. if you want to hook into the Dom rendering side of the event loop, you have useLayoutEffect too

Comment: @quirimmo - From [the description of `useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect), I think it wouldn't be any better, and could be worse, in terms of getting this information compared to `useEffect`. It happens sooner, and synchronously.

Comment: that's why as you see I told you as first thing to place the ref in the dependencies :)

Comment: @quirimmo ref.current can't be used as a dependency in useEffect() since it won't trigger a re-render on change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others mentioned here, your logic happens before image is loaded in most cases. So you have to get the image dimensions after the image has loaded because the browser doesn't  know the image dimensions before that.

I know you mentioned you want to do it with hooks, but unless you are doing something reusable, there's probably no need for hooks here. Or unless you are trying to understand them better, then it's fine.

One option would be to just use the `onLoad` event on the image element. This way you don't have to do all these checks if you have something in `ref.current` or is `img.complete === true`.

```
import React from 'react'

const DepthChartContent = props => {
  const handleImageLoad = (event) => {
    // Do whatever you want here
    const imageHeight = event.target.clientHeight;
  }

  return (
    <img
      ref={ref}
      className="depth-reference-bar"
      src={DepthRuler}
      alt="no ruler found"
      onLoad={handleImageLoad}
    />
  )
}
```

Don't get me wrong, I absolutely love hooks, but they aren't always the solution.

Comment: This is **much** better than hooking the `load` event after the fact. Just beware that an image can be *loaded* but not yet *laid out*.

Comment: I [combined mine with yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61865442/157247), this is a marked improvement.

Comment: Thanks. Who would have thought that image loading actually requires so much thought.

Comment: :-) Yeah. I didn't realize at first the element in question was an image... Glad you came by and pointed out the simple approach to hooking `load`!

Comment: True, the code sample provided has an `<img>`, but I just noticed that the question title mentions "div/image", but then the question below just refers to image and not a div. So both your solutions actually cover both these cases. In the end, OP now has few options to choose from depending on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** I originally missed the fact the element being measured is an `img`. Doh! So I posted a [community wiki answer combining the below with the `onload`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61865442/157247) shown in [Marko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61865326/157247).

---

`useEffect` callbacks happen immediately after render; the browser won't have had a chance to layout the elements yet. You're seeing the correct height *later* because of [this feature of console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection).

On most modern browsers, you should be able to fix this using a `setTimeout` with the value `0`. Or, alternately, two `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks (the first will happen just *before* the element is laid out, so not helpful; the second is afterward).

For instance:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let cancelled = false;
    const getHeight = () => {
        const { current } = ref; // `ref` will never be falsy
        if (!current || !current.clientHeight) {
            if (!cancelled) {
                requestAnimationFrame(getHeight);
            }
        } else {
            // Use `current.clientHeight` here
        }
    };
    getHeight();
    return () => {
        cancelled = true;
    };
}, []);
```

Of course, the height can change based on other things changing subsequently...

Live Example:

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

const DepthRuler = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";

const DepthChartContent = props => {
  const ref = useRef()
  const counterRef = useRef(0); // Just to count loops

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancelled = false;
    const getHeight = () => {
      ++counterRef.current;
      const { current } = ref; // `ref` will never be falsy
      if (!current || !current.clientHeight) {
        if (!cancelled) {
          requestAnimationFrame(getHeight);
        }
      } else {
        // Use `current.clientHeight` here
        console.log(`Height is ${current.clientHeight}, getHeight calls: ${counterRef.current}`);
      }
    };
    getHeight();
    return () => {
        cancelled = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <img
      ref={ref}
      className="depth-reference-bar"
      src={DepthRuler}
      alt="no ruler found"
    />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<DepthChartContent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry I downvoted your answer accidentally (upvoted it instead since it doesn't seem like there's a way to just undo :) ). What you're going is basically introducing a polling which will run multiple times until the image has been loaded and its dimensions are known. Same can be achieved by adding a load listener.

Comment: @AlexV - The naive `load` listener approach has a race condition, though. Yes, you can do it with a combination of `complete` and `load`, but the polling above is extremely lightweight and doesn't happen often enough to worry about. The only real issue with it is an image that's really of zero height. :-)

Comment: Anyway, the OP has a couple of good options to pick from, so we've done our jobs. :-)

Comment: How often the polling happens depends on network conditions and the size of the image (the slower the connection and the bigger the image, the longer it would be downloading and more times the polling callback would execute).

Comment: @AlexV - That's true, but again, the callback is trivial. This doesn't have the problem that the `load` solution has of the image being *loaded* but not yet *laid out*, which for me is a much bigger problem. The most robust but efficient solution would probably be a combination of both approaches, but if picking just one approach, I'd prefer the robust-and-efficient-enough one.

Comment: `[ref.current]` should not be used in dep array as React does not detect changes in ref. See  https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: @Shawn - Thanks for the comment. I've removed that part, not because it was wrong, but because it was irrelevant to the OP's code. :-) But while that link says that React doesn't notify you (trigger a render) when a ref changes (which is true), that doesn't mean a ref's current value should never appear in a dependency list. Sometimes it should, when you need the effect to run because the element it refers to changed as a result of a reactive value changing and causing a re-render ([like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ahykgd?file=src%2FApp.tsx)). But again...

Comment: ...that's not what the OP's code is doing, so it's irrelevant and unnecessarily complicated to mention it in the answer. Thanks again for flagging it up! :-)

Comment: e.g. let's say we do `useEffect(()=> console.log("123"),[ref.current.clientWidth])` in dep array on a div that will stretch as you increase viewport width. When you drag your browser window such that `ref.current.clientWidth` value increases, **you will not see useEffect get fired**. That's why `ref.current.clientWidth` has no effect in a dep array, and thus should not be used in dep array.

Comment: The example in your link is an exception! You're right with that, but it's a special case. As the **ref is re-created** - there's 3 <div>s and as you click + on either, it'll always unmount a <div> and mount the other. So if you want to detect the DOM mount/unmount, yes you can use [ref.current] in dep array. But otherwise, any nested attribute inside `current` should not be used in dep array because it'll never get triggered and causes misunderstanding that it will but in fact it's not.

Comment: @Shawn - The ref isn't recreated, its value just changes from one element to the next. (`ref` never changes, just `ref.current`). And yup, it's a somewhat unusual case. The key is that the ref's value has to be dependent (directly or indirectly) on a reactive value (as it will be when it's on an element the component is rendering, but may not be if you're using a ref for something else), since it relies on the reactive value changing and causing the render, and thus the effect. :-) Thanks again. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely when your effect executes the image hasn't been loaded yet thus its height is 0. Later when it has been loaded it updates the node's attributes and that's what you see in the console (since you're logging the node instance).

You can subscribe to the load event in your `useEffect` callback like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      ref.current.addEventListener('load', () => {
          console.log(ref.current.clientHeight);
      });
  }, [ref])
```

Comment: Hooking `load` *after* the element is in the DOM with a `src` is unreliable.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Another check can be added to determine whether an image has been loaded already or not. In the latter case it would be necessary to add the load listener, in the former the image dimensions can be used right away.

Comment: @Owais - Beware that as shown in the answer, this is not reliable. You *will* need to handle the race condition mentioned above. The issue will be particularly evident when the image comes from cache. You can check [`ref.current.complete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete).

Comment: Even with `complete`, though, if your timing is *just* wrong, it won't have laid out the image yet when you check that...

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, here's a combination of [Marko's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61865326/157247) and [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61864635/157247). It doesn't try to find the client height until/unless the image has been loaded, but will use `requestAnimationFrame` at most twice (because it should never take more than two, and frequently won't take any or just one) to get the height if the image hasn't been laid out yet:

```js
const { useEffect } = React;

const DepthRuler = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";

const DepthChartContent = props => {
  const handleImageLoad = (event) => {
    const {target} = event;
    let counter = 0;
    const done = () => {
      const imageHeight = target.clientHeight;
      console.log(`Height: ${imageHeight} (counter: ${counter})`);
    };
    const maybeDone = () => {
      if (target.clientHeight) {
        done();
      } else if (++counter < 3) {
        requestAnimationFrame(maybeDone);
      } else {
        console.log("Couldn't get height");
      }
    };
    maybeDone();
  };

  return (
    <img
      className="depth-reference-bar"
      src={DepthRuler}
      alt="no ruler found"
      onLoad={handleImageLoad}
    />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<DepthChartContent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

const DepthChartContent = props => {

    const ref = useRef();
    const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setImageHeight(ref.current.clientHeight)
    }, [ref.current]);

    return (
        <img
            ref={ref}
            className="depth-reference-bar"
            src={DepthRuler}
            alt="no ruler found"
        />
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One other solution I found for this is the [decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) method of the [HtmlImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

But make sure to check the [Browser compatiblity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode#browser_compatibility) first.

this method return a promise which is resolved when the image data are decoded.

```js
const {
  useEffect,
  useRef
} = React;

const App = (props) => {
  const imageUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/300X200";
  const imageRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(()=>{

    const image = imageRef.current
    
    if(image){

      image.decode()
        .then(() => {
          let {width,height} = image
          console.log(width,height)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log("Error while loading the image")
        })
    }
  
  },[]);
  
  return <img src={imageUrl} ref={imageRef}/>

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```