# Cant read property "name" of undefined. Property is defined, and so is the variable?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm making a small "notebook" app that will create, store, edit, delete multiple pages of text data.

I needed to make a system that would detect if you were at the end of the list, and create a new page, and then update the text in the editor.

I started getting an error "Cant read property "name" of undefined" yet its a clearly defined variable inside of "currentData"

I managed to snip most of the code out and this piece seems to be whats causing the issue:

```js
let currentData,
 currentPage = 0;

if (window.localStorage.getItem("nbEditorData")) {
    currentData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("nbEditorData"));
} else {
    currentData = [
         {
              name: "Page 1 Title", data: "Welcome"
         }
    ];
}

function visualizeData() {
    console.log(currentData);
    document.querySelector(".name").value = currentData[currentPage].name; // Error Occurs Here <-
    document.querySelector(".page").innerText = currentData[currentPage].data;
}

document.querySelector(".forward").addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (currentPage != currentPage.length) {
        currentPage++;
        visualizeData();
    } else {
        currentData.push({name: "New Page", data: ""});
        currentPage++;
        visualizeData();
    }

    if (currentPage + 1 == currentPage.length) {
        e.target.innerHTML = "";
    }
});
```

The full code is live here: https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/pen/GRoRmzw
[image]

Comment: `currentData[currentPage]` is `undefined` as of when that code runs. You may be getting tricked by [this "feature" of `console` on browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Im not expanding it while viewing.

Im logging the array before its modified, and the error is emitted before its modified. Plus if it was a visual error in the console, it shouldve been able to still create a new page on the notebook and put the "New Page" on its title.

Comment: @MisterSirCode so log the value of `currentPage`, too.   You'll probably find that it's set to `1` (which is off the end of the array)

Comment: @Alnitak but... thats exactly what im doing... Im logging "currentData" right before the error in that exact function

Comment: He said `currentPage`, not `currentData`. If you set a breakpoint on that line, you'll find that `currentData[currentPage]` is `undefined`. The JavaScript engine isn't wrong about that. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So how is it getting increased to 1? that statement is in an if statement that isnt true. I removed both increments and its still giving me that error

Comment: The condition **is** true. `0 != undefined` is `true`. `currentPage` is a number, and so `currentPage.length` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
if (currentPage != currentPage.length)
```

It should be referring to `currentData.length`.  You are probably also incrementing `currentPage` prematurely, causing the access into the `currentData` array to go beyond its current contents.

Even then, the test is likely incorrect.   In a well-formed program it should never be possible for `currentPage` to actually be greater-than or equal `currentPage.length` because JS arrays are *zero-based*.  To see otherwise indicates a logic error.

Comment: Ok, taking those changes into appreciation, the error is gone, and Im able to create new pages, jump ahead pages, and go back pages.

However, for some reason my logic must still be off, because its creating a new page every time you click the right arrow, rather than just jumping to previously created pages. Are you sure that if statement will work? I updated the codepen link above, if you want to see the changes

Comment: I would expect the logic to read (in pseudo-code) `if (current Page === currentData.length - 1) { add new page } ;  move to next page`

Comment: Well I just tried to make a change to the codepen, and I refreshed and I guess it screwed with something because my if statements went back to "currentPage.length" so I changed them again... Now Im getting the error AGAIN... FFS