# React nested map shows JSX in development, but not in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, nested-loops, development-environment

Data I'm using looks something like this:

`[ {id: 1, data: [{id: 2, name: 'test1'}, {id: 3, name: 'test1a'}]}, {id: 2, data: [{id: 4, name: 'test2'}, {id: 5, name: 'test2a'}]}, ]`

so, it's basically an array of objects, where every object has id and name property.

The idea is for every object to display a row with all items inside the data field of the object.

For that I'm using this component:

```js
const OptionsRow = ({
  options,
  isSelected,
  handleAnswerSelect,
  handleEdit,
  fetchLoading,
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  if (!options || !options.length) {
    return (
      <div className="OptionsRow" />
    );
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(options);

  return (
    <div className="OptionsRow">
      {
        options.map((oArr, i) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(oArr);
          // it logs this to console in the prod, but it returns nothing - works in development
          return (
            <div key={`option-index-${oArr.id}`}>
              <div className="step-indicator">
                {`${t('Korak')}: ${oArr.id}`}
              </div>
              <div className="Options-row">
                {
                  // eslint-disable-next-line arrow-body-style
                  oArr.data.map(o => {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                    console.log(o);
                    // doesnt log this in production
                    return (
                      <OptionItem
                        key={`${o.id} - ${o.name}`}
                        isSelected={!!isSelected(o.id)}
                        value={o}
                        handleSelectClick={() => handleAnswerSelect(o, i)}
                        handleEditClick={() => handleEdit(o)}
                        disabled={fetchLoading}
                      />
                    );
                  })
                }
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

There are similar questions on StackOverflow, but in most cases, the answer was just the missing return statement, which I use properly, so it seems to me.
This component works as expected on my local development server, but when deployed to the production there is no JSX displayed, the last executed line from the component is `console.log(oArr);` and the log from there looks ok.

Comment: From the symptom, it's that `options` is filled in **after** the component is rendered. You're probably being tricked by [deferred evaluation in the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection) (as many have been before you! :-) ). There's issue (race condition) in the parent component where it fills in `options` before rendering the above in dev, but doesn't in production. We can't help you diagnose that without seeing a [mcve] of the parent code.

Comment: It seems like that was the issue. I have wrapped this OptionsRow component into a conditional display like => `options && <OptionsRow />` and set the initial options state from empty array to null, and that fixed it.