# how to extract an element of an array

Tags: javascript

I have a newbie question
I log the following object

```
1) data
2) data.files
3) data.length (-> 0)
4) data.files[0] (-> undefined)
```

[image]

Here is a the console log for data object

```
{}
files: Array [ "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAzMAA......]
```

​Here is the console.log of data.files

```
[]
0: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAzMAAADKCAYAAACR3h76AAAYfWlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAWIWVWQdUFEu......."
​length: 1
```

​
Here is the gog of data.files.length

```
0
```

Here is the log of data.files[0]

```
undefined
```

I don't understand why data.files[0] is undefined

Comment: Please post an example of the object in question instead of a picture of it.

Comment: We can't really help without a fair bit more information, but it's likely you're running into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/console-log-of-element-children-shows-0-length-but-has-three-entries-when-expand) and your code trying to use `data.files[0]` is using it before `data.files` has entries added to it. But again, we can't help without much more information.

Comment: data.file[0] ? , what you need is datas.file[0]

Comment: @YorkChen Obviously a typo

Comment: then it should not be undefined, please check again, if it still happen, please show the entire code.

Comment: @YorkChen or the dupe explains it