# How to access object value inside static method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using `static getDerivedStateFromProps` from react to conditionally update the state.

This is the sample code:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        console.log(nextProps, prevState);
        if (prevState.web_data !== nextProps) {
            var data = nextProps.data;
            data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.created) - new Date(a.created));
            console.log(data[0]);
            // nextProps.getData({data[0].website_id});
            return {
                web_data: data,
                // selected_web_id: data[0].website_id
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In the above code `console.log(data[0])` returns the value of data at index 0 but when I try to access the object value inside the data[0] it throws error website_id is undefined.

The structure of data array is:

```
data = [{key:value, website_id...}, {key:value, website_id...}, {key:value, website_id...}, {key:value, website_id...}]
```

Comment: Don't stumble around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, not least for [this reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection). Instead, *turn on the lights* by using the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser. :-) Put a breakpoint on the `.sort` line. When your app hits the breakpoint, look at `data`. You'll find that it isn't quite what you think it is. It probably gets changed later.

Comment: *"it throws error website_id is undefined"* Please don't paraphrase errors. I can't work out what that might have said (it wouldn't make sense for it to say `website_id` was undefined, not with the code above; it might have said you can't read `website_id` of `undefined` or any of several other similar things). Instead, always use copy-and-paste to copy the **exact** error over (with quote markup) so that we know exactly what you're dealing with, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest instead of using console.log() to figure out the error try using the debugger and trace each step to find out why it is undefined.

According to me earlier the props are empty and that's why you are not able to access the object property.