# How to get the content of a document fragment?

Tags: javascript

I've made a small program to clone a template and log the cloned template on the console. However using chrome, only the first console.log statement will show an document-fragment object that can be unfolded, all other logs looks like strings.
I don't see this problem using firefox. So I wonder is this a chrome bug or is it something I'm not doing correctly?

```js
function clickHandler(event) {
  const insertPoint = document.querySelector('ul');

  let liTemplate = document.querySelector('#row').content.cloneNode(true);
  console.log(liTemplate);

  for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    liTemplate = document.querySelector('#row').content.cloneNode(true);
    console.log(liTemplate);
    liTemplate.querySelector('li').textContent = `row ${i}`;
    insertPoint.appendChild(liTemplate);
  }

}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (event) => clickHandler(event));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="module" src="demo.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <ul>
  </ul>

  <template id="row">
    <li>...</li>
  </template>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your Stack Snippet runs just fine in Chrome. All of the logs show a document fragment, and `row 1` and `row 2` show up in the list.

Comment: Strange, I and a couple of my college's are not able to unfold the console.log that is printed within the for loop. We are using chrome 91 under Windows. Might that be a cause of the issue?

Comment: @AlexJongman Looks like chrome issue to me, I am unable to unfold the same in chorme91

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem is specifically that you can't interact with the logged fragment after it's been logged in the Chrome console, it's just that the fragment is empty (you've used `appendChild` on the `li`, so it's no longer in the cloned template element). That's not a bug, it's just a difference in how Chrome and Firefox handle logged document fragments. What Firefox is showing you on the first line is a description of what the fragment looked like when it was logged, but if you expand the fragment, you can see that as of being expanded, it's empty (`firstChild` is `null`). Just a difference in how the consoles show fragments.

You probably already know this, but consoles show an indication of the object when it's logged, but show the state of the object as of when you expand it, more in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection).