# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" when accessing data from an array in React while retrieving data from react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting a weird error while using React and Redux

I access data from redux state using the following code:

```
const aboutGet = useSelector((state) => state.aboutGet);
const { loading, error, aboutData } = aboutGet;
console.log(aboutData);
```

The output of the above is the console output as follows:

```
    [{…}]
    0:
    aboutcontent: "Test Data"
    createdAt: "2021-09-19T08:59:01.548Z"
    image: "Some Image"
    title: "Some new About"
    updatedAt: "2021-09-20T03:04:09.014Z"
    __v: 0
    _id: "6146fbd5f4720923359e3338"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    length: 1
```

I now start by trying to access the _id from the above by using the following lines of code:

```
const aboutId = aboutData[0]._id;
console.log(aboutId);
```

This gives me the following error:

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Can someone please help and let me know where I am going wrong and what I need to do to access the data inside aboutData.

Many thanks and regards
Teejay

Comment: Please `JSON.stringify` the aboutData and log it and add that to your post. Your copy-pasted "output" is confusing.

Comment: Also, why didn't you try to `console.log` `aboutData[0]`?

Comment: You're probably running into [this often-confusing feature of the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection).

Comment: Nano Miratus: I did try to console.log aboutData[0] also. Still getting the same error

Comment: can you share the output of `aboutGet` I think something is going wrong with your destructuring

Comment: ImAtWar Sir, here is the output of aboutGet     {loading: false, aboutData: Array(1)}
aboutData: Array(1)
0:
aboutcontent: "Test Data"
createdAt: "2021-09-19T08:59:01.548Z"
image: "Some Other Image"
title: "Some new About"
updatedAt: "2021-09-20T03:04:09.014Z"
__v: 0
_id: "6146fbd5f4720923359e3338"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
loading: false
[[Prototype]]: Object