# Array is looking empty, but have 4 objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I make a async function to get offers, and add to array with another array. But the offers array are looking empty in console, but when I click shows the itens.

The products are comming that's isn't the problem. The problem is that I can't add the `arrayOffers` to `itemsArray`.

OBS: the forEach is from `p-interation` lib.

this is my code.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (auth && auth._id) {
            const fetchUserVisitedProducts = async (id) => {
                const user = await getPublicUserRequest(id);
                let array = [];

                forEach(user.offers_visited, async (id) => {
                    const offers = await getOfferRequest(id)
                    array.push(offers)
                });
                const arrayOffers = array;
                console.log(arrayOffers)
                const itemsArray = [ ...user.barbadas_visited, ...arrayOffers]
                console.log(itemsArray)
                
            }    
            fetchUserVisitedProducts(auth._id)
        }
  
    },[auth])
```

In the image, I see one array with 4 objects, but looks empty. And another array that is correct.

[image: IMAGE ARRAYS]

Comment: Looks like an async issue, you're not awaiting your `forEach()` call before logging so it's empty when first logged, but Chrome logs live arrays, so it gets updated in the view later.

Comment: `Array is looking empty, but have 4 objects` The reason for this is answered here: [console.log of element.children shows 0 length but has three entries when expanded later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/console-log-of-element-children-shows-0-length-but-has-three-entries-when-expand)

Comment: I agree with your comment ! I trying to find a soluction.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing the

```
 forEach(user.offers_visited, async (id) => {
    const offers = await getOfferRequest(id)
    array.push(offers)
 });
```

with

```
  for (const id of user.offers_visited) {
    const offers = await getOfferRequest(id)
    array.push(offers)
  }
```

as `forEach` is not meant to be used with async.

Comment: This `forEach` is from `p-interation` lib, and work I another async function.

PS: I try your code but didnt work :(

Comment: @JoaoVitorLima that’s an important information that belongs to the question. Anyhow, the `forEach` of p-interation returns a promise so `await forEach(…`. But if `user.offers_visited` is an array the `for … of` solution has to work.

Comment: I try to add `for .. of`, but shows `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` in console.

Comment: @JoaoVitorLima That is a react error not related to the shown code.

Comment: The for…of didnt work. Because, everthing after the function arent working.