# objects not properly pushed in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

The code below is supposed to decompose a json object sent from Postman into smaller objects that will be stored in a array. The problem is that if I console.log the result, I do see each and every objects decomposed as expected but the array.push method only push the last element of the inner array :

```
app.post('/commande',async(req,res)=>{

if( await authentification(req.query.login, req.query.pass)){

  var data = req.body.data; // array containing json object to be posted
  var dataLength = data.length;
  var bigObj= []; //array to store objects
  for (var i = 0; i<dataLength; i++) {

    var orderLines = data[i].orderLines;//array of orders
    var info ={};// object unit
    info.CptClient = data[i].clientAccount;
    info.customerOrderNumber= data[i].customerOrderNumber;
    info.orderLabel = data[i].orderLabel;
    var shipTo = data[i].shipTo;
    info.recepientName = shipTo.recepientName;
    info.contactName = shipTo.contactName;
    info.ad1 = shipTo.ad1;
    info.ad2 = shipTo.ad2;
    info.ad3 = shipTo.ad3;
    info.postalCode = shipTo.postalCode;
//"etc..."

  //
  for (var j = 0; j<orderLines.length;j++) {
    
    info.itemRef = orderLines[j].itemRef;
    info.itemQty = orderLines[j].itemQty;
    info.unitPrice = orderLines[j].unitPrice;
    
       
    
    console.log(info);//displays unique orderLabel :      ABC01 ABC02 ABC03 XYZ01 XYZ02 XYZ03
    bigObj.push(info); // stores only last of each type : ABC03 ABC03 ABC03 XYZ03 XYZ03 XYZ03
 
}
  }
res.json(bigObj)
}else {
  res.send("not authorized");
}

})
```

As explained in the comments, the console.log displays the right information as the objects are being created but the push method somehow would only push the last element of the orderLines array. Is there somebody to explain this phenomenon? Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: The problem is the function scope of variables defined with `var` (there's only one `info` variable and not one per loop iteration). Get rid of that legacy thing and use `let` and `const` instead.

Comment: @Andreas - Even though there will only be one `info` *variable*, there will still be a different object assigned to it in each loop. `var info = {};` becomes `info = {};`. (Not that getting rid of `var` isn't **very** good advice anyway!)

Comment: @​Njdc Wide - In your "etc." placeholder in the code, is there anything that's asynchronous? Any `await` or an asynchronous callback?

Comment: info.itemRef, for example, will be set over and over again by the j loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, but that doesn't change the fact that `info` can only store one object and only `info` is pushed into the array: `bigObj.push(info);`

Comment: @Andreas - Indeed, but that's not because of `var` and wouldn't be fixed by `let`, it's a logic flaw in the function (the inner loop using `j` should create a new object, most likely).

Comment: @​Njdc Wide - Why are you repeatedly pushing the same object into the array in the inner loop using `j`? As @James pointed out, that loop overwrites previous values of `info`'s properties. Did you mean to create a new object for each loop iteration?

Comment: no, there is no async element in the etc.

Comment: how comes the console.log(info) displays the right information that the array.push won't catch and store in an array?

Comment: I tried with let, const and even nothing, I still get the same result.

Comment: @NjdcWide - Because you're doing this with a console (I'm assuming this is running in Node.js) that shows you what you logged as of a point in time (browser consoles work [slightly differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection)), and as of that point in time, `info` had the information you expect. But then you overwrite the information on the next loop, erasing the previous value that was there.

Comment: Again: Why are you pushing the **same object** repeatedly rather than creating a new object? Separately, it's hard to help you with this without seeing the input you receive and the output you expect.

Comment: And yes T.J , the goal was to create a new object for each loop iteration.

Comment: Then you need to do that inside the `for (var j = 0; j<orderLines.length;j++)` loop. Currently, you aren't.

Comment: OK, got it... I put everything in the j loop and now all objects are unique. Thank you guys for your assistance.

Comment: Glad that helped! Do look into `let`, `const`, and `for-of` loops -- they help a lot. :-) (I cover them in my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys* on all the new stuff in ES2015-ES2020 -- links in my profile if you're interested.)