# Javascript replacing properties as empty strings or 0's with undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, string, null, undefined

I'm developing on Angular 12 + Material for the front-end part of a full-stack project and I'm before an apparently Javascript/ES/Node/Angular bug which is driving me absolutely crazy because it has no sense at all.

I have an object called "data" one of whose properties could be and usually are empty strings for they are hidable sections of a blog page.

```
  let data = {
    titulo: cbidioma.titulo,
    subtitulo: cbidioma.subtitulo,
    contenido: "",
    contenido2: cbidioma.contenido2,
    contenido3: cbidioma.contenido3,
    contenido4: cbidioma.contenido4,
    blockquote: cbidioma.blockquote,
    fid_idioma: cbidioma.fid_idioma,
    fid_entradablog: this.entradaBlog.entradaBlog_id,
  };
  console.log("DATA",data);
```

More precisely, the property called "contenido" or "content" is the one that made me realize, but it's also happening with any other property or javascript object which I could declare in my app components.

As logic says, "contenido" property should remain an empty string when prompting it at the console. However, it is unexplainably replaced by an **undefined value** that, in a even odder way, only shows up when expanding the object definition at the console.

Let me explain with an image

[Paranormal object transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlLH8.png)

This bug or whatever is driving me and my team somehow a little bit mad and we're in desperate need of somebody who only can explain what is happening here.

Thank you in advance for reading :3

UPDATE:
Despite how much as I thought I had checked it, I eventually found a piece of asynchronous code being executed onto the object and, how not, making a somehow wrongly planned sanitizing
object[key] = !object[key] ? undefined : object[key];

Thank you everyone for your answers, both published up to now were just in the right spot of the answer :)

Comment: You have code **after** the `console.log` that is making those changes to the object, see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection).

Comment: Look at that little blue `i` icon. If you hover or click on that what does it say?