# Typescript / Ionic count elements in array returns always 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm coding an Ionic Application, that stores some form entries and some options by using the "storage". Now I would like to count the options, but I'm always getting a zero.

I'm using the following code:

```
async getAllEntries()
{
let count = 0;
this.trackingEntries = [];
this.storage.forEach((value, key, index) => 
{
  if (key != "Options0" && key != "Options1"  && key != "Options2"  && key != "Options3"  )
  {
    this.trackingEntries.push(value);
    count++;
  }
})
console.log(this.trackingEntries);  
console.log("Count: " + count);
```

}

console.log(this.trackingEntries) returns the following object:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": "1663677073",
        "tracking": [
            "6",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6"
        ]
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "1663677073",
        "tracking": [
            "2",
            "2",
            "2",
            "2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "1663677073",
        "tracking": [
            "2",
            "2",
            "2",
            "2"
        ]
    }
]
```

But the count variable always is zero. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `this.storage`? If it's an array, your callback parameter list is wrong; the `if` condition will always be true. See [MDN's `forEach` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (or anyone else's).

Comment: If you're seeing entries in `this.trackingEntries` but `count` is `0`, the entries aren't being added by the code shown (you might be getting hit by [this subtle `console.log` behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection)). There's no question that `count` is incremented after each call to `push` in that code.

Comment: It's this angular package: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage

Comment: If I print the count in the for loop I get values 1,2,3 and so on

Comment: *"If I print the count in the for loop I get values 1,2,3 and so on"* I'm sorry, but it's flatly impossible for that to be the case with the code in the question. The code you're actually running must be different.

Comment: [The usage](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage) seems to indicate that the right signature for this method should be `storage.forEach((key, value, index) => { /* ... */ }` and not `(value, key, index)`. It also seems that we are not talking about [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#syntax). The 3 parameter signature for that one looks like `(element, index, array)`.

Comment: *"It's this angular package"* So, **not** an array like you said it was in the title, then.

Comment: Just as a final point: You're starting with a blank array and `count = 0`, then pushing elements to it and incrementing `count`. What's the point of `count`? Just use `this.trackingEntries.length`.

Comment: this.trackingEntries.length also returns 0

Comment: Then your condition is never true and no entries are being added by the code shown, probably for the reason [@Octavian mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73786872/#comment130292304_73786872). The entries you see are added **later**, by code not shown, and you're running into [the `console.log` issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/) that [I linked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73786872/typescript-ionic-count-elements-in-array-returns-always-0#comment130292110_73786872).

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks for not helping and telling nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using a "then".

```
async getAllPottyTrackingEntries() {
this.trackingEntries = [];
this.storage.forEach((value, key, index) => {
    if (key != "Options0" && key != "Options1" && key != "Options2" && key != "Options3") {
        this.trackingEntries.push(value);
    }
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Count: " + this.trackingEntries.length)
});
```

}