# Array of objects stored in instance variable is considred empty even if its not

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am working with a controller that has a list of Objects, the problem is i cant access the Objects stored in the objList array of the CondController. Which gives me this error:

```
build_strategy_page.js:103 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insert_cond')
    at build_conds (build_strategy_page.js:103:17)
```

Upon debugging i found out that there is problem with Values of the arrays in the CondController Instance
When i console log the instance of the object. At first glance it seems like the arrays of the object are empty but when i fold out the info, it is clear that they are not.

[image]

When i console.log lenght of the array "objList" it is 0 and when i console.log the array itself by calling the instance variable "condListController.objList"

i get a conflicted message again, where the console says [[prototype]]:Array(0) but shows values when pressed and folded out:

I am completely lost here i never had a bug so weird before, anyone have a clue what could be wrong?
[image]

```
const condListController = new CondController();
async function build_conds() {
  const json = await getJson("load_conditions");
  const buy_conds = json.buy_conds;
  const sell_conds = json.sell_conds;

  optimizer_params(buy_conds, "_BUY", "param_buy");
  // optimizer_params(sell_conds, "_SELL", "param_sell");
  console.log(buy_conds);

  for (let i = 0; i < buy_conds.length; i++) {
    console.log(buy_conds[i].fk_list_id, "cond");
    console.log(condListController, "condListController this outputs the controller");
    console.log(condListController.objList.length); // outputs 0
    console.log(condListController.objList); // but it is not empty
    let condManager = condListController.getKey(buy_conds[i].fk_list_id);
    condManager.insert_cond(buy_conds[i].indicator_json, which_row(buy_conds[i].list_row), buy_conds[i].condition_id);
  }
}


export class CondController {
  constructor() {
    this.objList = [];
    this.obj = {};
    //ensure incrementing id
    this.countArray = [];
  }
  count() {
    return this.countArray.length;
  }

  createCondManager(identifier, primary_key) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.primary_key = primary_key;

    const taskManager = new CondManager(this.identifier, this.primary_key);
    this.objList.push(taskManager);

    // Assign the TaskManager instance to this.obj using the identifier as the key
    this.obj[this.identifier] = taskManager;

    // just pushing something of no value
    this.countArray.push(0);

    return taskManager;
  }

  addCond(identifier, text, column) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.text = text;
    this.column = column;
    const current_cond_list = this.obj[this.identifier];
    current_cond_list.insert_cond(this.text, this.column);
  }

  getKey(key) {
    this.key = key;

    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.objList.length; i++) {
      if (this.objList[i].primary_key === this.key) {
        return this.objList[i];
      }
    }
  }
}

class CondManager {
  constructor(identifier, primary_key) {
    this.primary_key = primary_key;
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.conds = [];
  }
  insert_cond(text, column, id) {
    this.conds.push({ text, column, id });
  }
}
```

Comment: The array was empty when you **logged** it, but had something in it later when you expanded it in the console. See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: A more directly-applicable question (with answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/console-log-of-element-children-shows-0-length-but-has-three-entries-when-expand